# How to access object properties in a JSON file using literals obtained from the same file

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, underscore.js

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart with d3 from data in a JSON file.  Each bar would have ties, losses, and wins for a particular month.

JSON file:

```
{
    "name": "FHS",
    "points": 3000,
    "ties": 3,
    "losses": 19,
    "wins": 50,
    "games": {
        "2010-09": { "ties": 1, "losses": 2, "wins": 16 },
        "2010-10": { "ties": 2, "losses": 5, "wins": 13 },
        "2010-11": { "ties": 0, "losses": 12, "wins": 21 }
    }
}
```

I've already used some of the data just fine using the d3.json functionality.  For example:

```
d3.json("data.json",function(error,data)
    {
        alert(data.name);
        alert(data.points);
        // etc.
    });
```

But here's where it gets interesting (fyi, I'm using the underscore library to grab each property of "games"...perhaps this is where I'm going wrong?).  If I try the following:

```
_.keys(data.games).forEach(function(d)
    {
        alert(d);
    });
```

I get 2010-09, 2010-10, 2010-11 in three different alert boxes...perfect!  BUT, if I try the following:

```
_.keys(data.games).forEach(function(d)
    {
        alert(d.ties);
    });
```

I get undefined :/  In fact, another problem that I see arising is that

```
alert(data.games.2010-09.ties);
```

should work (if the property names didn't begin with integers or have hyphens...), but won't because of the format of the literal ("2010-09")...so, my main question is how to dynamically access nested object properties in such a manner that would make generating a chart simple.  I've tried to include enough context, but please let me know if you would like any more information.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: consider using _.each which I think will pass you both the key and the value if you want it.

Comment: @Superboggly: Thanks, I'll have to check that one out too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get undefined in the alert box because `d`, inside this function, is a string – "2010-09", "2010-10", "2010-11", etc – since you're iterating over the array of strings returned by `_.keys(data.games)`.

So, `alert(d.ties)` is like calling `alert("2010-09".ties)`, which is expectedly undefined.

But, building on what Lars explained,

```
_.keys(data.games).forEach(function(d)
{
    alert(data.games[d].ties);
});
```

is how you'd get at the data.

P.S. `console.log(data.games[d].ties)` is the more robust way (and hence usually the preferred way) to debug javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info.  I was able to figure out calling `data.games[d].ties` pretty much immediately after reading Lars's answer.  I'll have to keep in mind the console.log() function for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

You can enclose keys in `[""]` to access the value, i.e. `alert(data.games["2010-09"].ties);` will work. You might also be interested in the d3 functions to work with key-value structures; see [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_keys).

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.  I have yet to look into d3.keys, but within the forEach loop I tried `alert(data.games[d].ties);`, and that seemed to work perfectly.  I just need to play around with it some more.  Thanks!